# Accessing variable from one job in another job within a GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow defined as follows:

```yaml
name: Test workflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  check-pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check PRs
        id: check-prs
        run: |
          branch_name=${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}
          pr_count=$(curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
                        --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
                        "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls?state=open&head=${{ github.repository_owner }}:${branch_name}" \
                        | jq length)
          if [ $pr_count -eq 1 ]; then
            pr_number=$(curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
                            --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
                            "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls?state=open&head=${{ github.repository_owner }}:${branch_name}" \
                            | jq -r '.[0].number')
            echo "PR_NUMBER=$pr_number" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "PR count is not equal to 1. Exiting workflow."
            exit 1
          fi
  publish:
    needs: [check-pr]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      PR_NUMBER: ${{ needs.check-pr.env.PR_NUMBER }}
    name: publish v0.0.1.dev$PR_NUMBER
    steps:
      # ...
```

In this workflow, I have two jobs: `check-pr` and `publish`. The `check-pr` job retrieves the PR number based on the branch name and sets it as an environment variable using `$GITHUB_ENV`.

I want to access the value of the `PR_NUMBER` variable, which is written to `$GITHUB_ENV` in the check-pr job, within the publish job. However, when I try to use `$PR_NUMBER` in the publish job, it doesn't seem to have the expected value.

I have already confirmed that the `check-pr` job sets the `PR_NUMBER` correctly by logging it to the console. However, I'm unable to access it in the publish job.

Could someone please guide me on how to properly access the `PR_NUMBER` variable written in `$GITHUB_ENV` from the `check-pr` job in the `publish` job? Am I missing any additional configuration or syntax?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use an [output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) instead. The env vars are not propagated across jobs. See [Defining outputs for jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs).

Comment: You might find your action easier to read if you just use the gh cli to access the GH API rather than raw curl. https://cli.github.com/manual/gh. Also you are making two of the same api calls and then filtering the results. Consider making one api call, saving that output and then just running jq on that output for your differently desired values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem) stated in the comment above, you can't propagate env variables between jobs, only outputs.

To use `outputs`, you would need to update your workflow as below:

```
name: Test workflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  check-pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
       PR_NUMBER: ${{ steps.check-prs.outputs.PR_NUMBER }}
    steps:
      - name: Check PRs
        id: check-prs
        run: |
          branch_name=${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}
          pr_count=$(curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
                        --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
                        "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls?state=open&head=${{ github.repository_owner }}:${branch_name}" \
                        | jq length)
          if [ $pr_count -eq 1 ]; then
            pr_number=$(curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
                            --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
                            "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls?state=open&head=${{ github.repository_owner }}:${branch_name}" \
                            | jq -r '.[0].number')
            echo "PR_NUMBER=$pr_number" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "PR count is not equal to 1. Exiting workflow."
            exit 1
          fi
  publish:
    needs: [check-pr]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      PR_NUMBER: ${{ needs.check-pr.outputs.PR_NUMBER }}
    name: publish v0.0.1.dev$PR_NUMBER
    steps:
      # ...
```

It's similar to what you have done with `env`, however you need to set the output field in the first job to be able to get the value in the second job by using `${{ needs.check-pr.outputs.PR_NUMBER }}`

References:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter